# Can I use pd.concat to add new columns equal to other columns in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, where-clause, benchmarking

I am new to Python and am converting SQL to Python and want to learn the most efficient way to process a large dataset (rows > 1 million and columns > 100). I need to create multiple new columns based on other columns in the DataFrame. I have recently learned how to use pd.concat for new boolean columns, but I also have some non-boolean columns that rely on the values of other columns.

In SQL I would use a single case statement (case when age > 1000 then sample_id else 0 end as custom1, etc...). In Python I can achieve the same result in 2 steps (pd.concat + loc find & replace) as shown below. I have seen references in other posts to using the apply method but have also read in other posts that the apply method can be inefficient.

My question is then, for the code shown below, is there a more efficient way to do this? Can I do it all in one step within the pd.concat (so far I haven't been able to get that to work)? I am okay doing it in 2 steps if necessary. I need to be able to handle large integers (100 billion) in my custom1 element and have decimals in my custom2 element.

And finally, I tried using multiple separate np.where statements but received a warning that my DataFrame was fragmented and that I should try to use concat. So I am not sure which approach overall is most efficient or recommended.

*Update* - after receiving a comment and an answer pointing me towards use of np.where, I decided to test the approaches. Using a data set with 2.7 million rows and 80 columns, I added 25 new columns. First approach was to use the concat + df.loc replace as shown in this post. Second approach was to use np.where. I ran the test 10 times and np.where was faster in all 10 trials. As noted above, I think repeated use of np.where in this way can cause fragmentation, so I suppose now my decision comes down to faster np.where with potential fragmentation vs. slower use of concat without risk of fragmentation. Any further insight on this final update is appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [120, 4000],
                   'weight': [505.31, 29.01],
                   'sample_id': [999999999999, 555555555555]},
                 index=['rock1', 'rock2'])

#step 1: efficiently create starting custom columns using concat
df = pd.concat(
     [
        df,
        (df["age"] > 1000).rename("custom1").astype(int),
        (df["weight"] < 100).rename("custom2").astype(float),
     ],
     axis=1,
)

#step2: assign final values to custom columns based on other column values
df.loc[df.custom1 == 1, 'custom1'] = (df['sample_id'])
df.loc[df.custom2 == 1, 'custom2'] = (df['weight'] / 2)
```

Thanks for any feedback you can provide...I appreciate your time helping me.

Comment: It would be wise to utilize, numpy for such actions

Comment: Thanks for feedback @ING|0R1AM0R1 and @Stef. I updated post above related to prior attempts to use np.where.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is using numpy [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['custom1'] = np.where(df.age.gt(1000), df.sample_id, 0)
df['custom2'] = np.where(df.weight.lt(100), df.weight / 2, 0)
```